# how to append an element under a sequence in a way that respects XSD defined order

Tags: xml, dom, xslt, xsd, schema

I have an input XML (its insurance industry compliant  to ACORD schema) coming and am tasked with inserting an element into it so that its still schema compliant. The brief structure of input XML is:

```
<Root>
  <Child>
    <Sub-Child>
      <a>
      <b>
      <c>
      <d>
      <e>
      <f>
    </Sub-Child>
  <Child>
</Root>
```

Where `<a> <b> <c> <d> <e> <f>` are all in a sequence and **optional**. Now, I have to insert an element after `<c>` but I don't know if siblings will ever be present. I've so far used `XSLT` in my project avoiding `JAXB` by all possible means. Is it still possible to achieve this with `XSLT` (my first preference) or to a minimum without generating JAXB classes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. I don't think there is something which automatically will consider the schema. If the complexity is not to high you can implement sequences of name template calls (e.g  a,b,c,d,e,f for Sub-Child) each of this named templates has to decide whether to take the element from input XML or create a new one (depending on some variable?).

Comment: This a,b,c,d,e,f is just an example, actually, there are almost 50 elements. It'll be too cumbersome to actually test each element and its siblings to decide where to insert new element. Do you know of any API which can order the elements based on schema if I insert new element as the last child of Sub-Child?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using XSLT. I suspect it is not even easy using JAXB classes.

What needs to be done is to load and parse the XSD, and then write code that interprets the rules on element sequences to determine which element can be inserted where - this requires creating the [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) corresponding to the rules and then apply it.

Comment: Please help me understand how it is not easy using JAXB. Can I not unmarshall my XML, add element as an object to unmarshalled objects and marshall it again according  XSD

Comment: We didn't find a way other than comparing to the possible, optional siblings.  (Because we were inserting near the end, we only had to test for the couple of possibilities that might come after the new element, and then back up if neither were present.)